# Chrome extension to display Google Drive notifications?

Tags: chrome, google-drive

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that displays unread/unresolved comments in form of an unread icon count such as illustrated by another example below (reddit).

I would like this extension icon to replace the (annoying) *Open Discussion* emails that Google Drive keeps sending me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Checker Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-google-d/pppfmbnpgflleackdcojndfgpiboghga?hl=en-US). I think it does exactly what you want. And you can turn off the email notifications from Drive by going to the Gear icon and then to Settings and then Notifications. You can actually turn on the Option of "Getting updates about Google Drive items in your browser". Maybe that will do as well.